# Is it possible to use tablesorter pager without server side?

Tags: json, ajax, server, tablesorter

I want tablesorter to build a table and paging with a json-string/array I make manually with data from the server.
I know I can implement paging by getting a json-file with ajax from the server, but this is not an option for me, since the amount of data is huge and can change.
The tablesorter Pager requires an ajax-url for that matter which I cannot offer.

The context is: I have like 20k rows I need to display in a table with paging. Using pager the classic way after building the table takes too response time from the server. I have a way to get all of the rows with an ajax-get call into an array.

Is there a way to use just a json-string/array to make the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of tablesorter without server side is not possible.

We used [this client side tablesorter plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Paginate-Sort-Filter-Table-Sortable.html).